# What technology to use for a RIA

Tags: ria, erp

I have to develop a online business software solution (similar to ERP) for a company to manage the information exchange for internal use and with external partners. It should be online.

What technology should I use, I have checked framewroks like: Flex, Silverlight, Google/GWT, sencha (ExtJS), jQuery, DoJo, Telereik, Infrajistics and others similar. But they seam to be very low level programming. May be this is advantage for other projects, where you need more flexibility, but this project is stright forward.

I need something more focused on business software (tables, forms, processes) where and eventually more efficient with less coding, or something I can save time.

Is force.com an option? But I can not install this on the customer's servers...

Do you have any ideas for me for a web based framework focused on business applications?

Answer (score 0):

I would have recommended Force.com or Azure ERP for the cloud based solution. However if you are looking for customer server hosted solution you can also explore [Dynamics ERP](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics/default.aspx) . If Dynamics is too heavy for your needs then you can consider this [Silverlight based ERP framework](http://xerpdotnet.codeplex.com/)